# unique number of words in a propertyfile

Tags: java

What is the optimum way  to count the unique number of words in a propertyfile (Just the Values) in java (java 1.8)
for example entries may be:

```
key1=This is my value for error {0}
key2=This is success message.Great.
```

Output should be 10 (including {0})

What I tried

```
property.load(in);

            Enumeration em = property.keys();
            while (em.hasMoreElements()) {
                String str = (String) em.nextElement();
                completeString =completeString+property.get(str);

            }
Set<String> myset=new HashSet<>();
        String s[]=completeString.split("[ .]");

        for(int i=1;i<s.length;i++){

                myset.add(s[i]);

         }

         for (String sss: myset){

            System.out.println(sss);

        }
```

System.out.println(myset.size());

Do we have a simpler way in java 1.8

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: What is wrong with the actual solution ? Except that you should population the `HashSet` in the iteration instead of concatenaning a `completeString`.

Comment: Please post your full code, and fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

## Data used :

I used a dummy `Properties`

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("A", "This is my value for error {0}");
prop.put("B", "This is success message.Great.");
```

---

## Good old Java:

Using the same logic you used, you can simply split the `String` of each property in the iteration :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

Enumeration em = property.keys();

while (em.hasMoreElements()) {
    String str = (String) em.nextElement();
    for(String s : str.split("[ .]")){
        set.add(s);
    }
}
```

---

## In Java 8 - Stream API :

Define the pattern to split each "word".

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ .]");
```

Now, first let's get our `Stream<String>` for our values.

You can either take a `List<Object>` :

```
Stream<String> stream = 
    //Create a `List<Object>` from the enumeration and stream it
    Collections.list(prop.elements()).stream() 
        //Convert in String
        .map(o -> (String)o);
```

Or `Stream` the `Map.Entry` of the `Properties` :

```
Stream<String> stream =
    prop.entrySet().stream() //Iterate the Map.Entry<Object,Object>
        .map(e -> (String)e.getValue())
```

(Not sure which is more efficient)

---

Then, all you have to do is to `flatMap` the `Stream` to split each `String` into new `Stream<String>`.

```
    stream.flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream) //split based on the pattern define and return a new `Stream<String>`
```

Then collect the `Stream` into a `Set`

```
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()); //collect in a `Set<String>`
```

The result would be a nice `Set` printed like:

```
[Great, success, for, This, {0}, is, my, error, message, value]
```

## Summary :

```
Set<String> set = 
        prop.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> (String)e.getValue())
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile(pattern)::splitAsStream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: He was asking if there is some better solution with the Java 8, no offense, against your post, also good point. But I guess maybe there will be better solution with the streams and filters :)

Comment: Indeed, even if this is still working in Java 8 ;) will add the Stream solution...

Comment: Literally there is from my pov nothing like "better or worse" according to java 8 vs java 7, streams offers ususally shorter code. Thanks mate ;)

Comment: No offense taken @xxxvodnikxxx ;) check that new solution then. Not sure this is really better....

Comment: thanks  for the solution- Java 8 gives shorter but sometimes it look so cryptic

Comment: @sajna, I can add more explanation if this is unclear.